# Are Attribute.GetCustomAttributes and MemberInfo.GetCustomAttributes interchangeable?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, attributes

If I recall it correctly, [`Attribute.GetCustomAttributes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.attribute.getcustomattributes) was initially introduced because [`MemberInfo.GetCustomAttributes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.memberinfo.getcustomattributes?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Reflection_MemberInfo_GetCustomAttributes_System_Type_System_Boolean_) had a bug for **fields and events.**

Now I'm trying to find any links to this issue, to understand if they're **completely** interchangeable in modern .NET Framework (if this bug was fixed), but I can't. I may be totally wrong about it, then please explain the correct history, and why there are two ways of doing the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have missed this remarks section in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.memberinfo.getcustomattributes?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Reflection_MemberInfo_GetCustomAttributes_System_Type_System_Boolean_), which explains it all:

> **Remarks**
>
> This method ignores the `inherit` parameter for properties and
>   events. To search the inheritance chain for attributes on properties
>   and events, use the appropriate overloads of the
>   [Attribute.GetCustomAttributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.attribute.getcustomattributes?view=netframework-4.8) method.

And I was wrong about fields. This issue is only for **properties and events**.

Hope this question will improve this issue googlability.